# HTACCESS 'value.html' to '*.html?id=value'

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am trying to change a url of `value.html` to `*.html?id=value` with htaccess

Example :

```
http://example.com/post_name/post_name_page_2.html
```

to :

```
http://example.com/post_name/post_name_page_2.html?page_number_0=2
```

I have tried this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST}  %1.html? [R=302,L,NE] 
RewriteRule ^/(.*)\?id=(.+?)\s [NC]
```

But it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try lik this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /file.html?id=%1 [L,R]
```

This will redirect :

```
/foo.html
```

to

```
/file.html?id=foo
```

%1 is part of the regex in RewriteCond, it contains the value "foo"

Edit :
To redirect from

- http://example.com/post_name/post_name_page_2.html

to :

- http://example.com/post_name/post_name_page_2.html?page_number_0=2

You need the following code

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^_]+)_([0-9]+)\.html$ /$1/$2_$3.html?page_number_0=$3 [NC,L,R]
```

**RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$** is important here to avoid  redirect loop error.

Comment: Says: "The page isn't redirecting properly" 
and the link that is outputted by the RewriteRule is :
http://example.com/file.html?id=file

Comment: this again : 
The page isn't redirecting properly

Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.

    This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies.

Comment: This time the output url was right ,but that error why ?

Comment: @LuarbBalla Try Clearing your browser's cache.

Comment: Sorry for bothering you again @Starkeen , i found another problem while testing , so if i put some values into the link after the rule applies those values disapear. 
example : http://example.com/post_name/post_name_page_2.html?type=1
the "?type=1" does not appear. I tried modifying but with no success .
I think , for the code inside the .htaccess file to work , i should enter &type=1 so when it changes to ?page_number_0=2&type=1 . I have 3 variables i need to enter there , in the end it should look like this : link_2.html?page_number_0=2&fullscreen=off&ref=root&type=1.